# How to handle external audio file access on native android app (Kotlin) permission based on different API LEVEL

Tags: android, kotlin, android-permissions

I have only two permissions for grabing audio file

On ***AndroidManifest.xml***

```
<!-- READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE:: Works in API LEVEL 29, 30 but not above -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<!-- READ_MEDIA_AUDIO:: Works in API LEVEL 31 and above -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_AUDIO" />
```

I implement both so that my app works almost all API levels, and then I add EasyPermission library for handling runtime access permission.

On ***build.gradle***

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.10.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.8.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'

    // Easy Permissions
    implementation 'com.vmadalin:easypermissions-ktx:1.0.0'
}
```

Now the problem is I am not able to figuire out that how can I implement both permissions at onece.

Here's my ***MainActivity.kt*** that I tried my best. It works perfectly for one of these permissions but not both.

```
package com.playmakers.permissiontest

import android.content.Intent
import android.os.Build
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.annotation.RequiresApi
import com.vmadalin.easypermissions.EasyPermissions
import com.vmadalin.easypermissions.dialogs.SettingsDialog

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), EasyPermissions.PermissionCallbacks {

    companion object{
        const val PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE = 1
    }


    @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.TIRAMISU)
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val button = findViewById<Button>(R.id.button)

        button.setOnClickListener {
            if(hasStoragePermission()){
                startActivity(Intent(this, SecondActivity::class.java))
            } else {
                requestStoragePermission()
            }
        }
    }

    @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.TIRAMISU)
    private fun hasStoragePermission() =
        EasyPermissions.hasPermissions(this, android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) || EasyPermissions.hasPermissions(this, android.Manifest.permission.READ_MEDIA_AUDIO)

    @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.TIRAMISU)
    private fun requestStoragePermission(){
        EasyPermissions.requestPermissions(
            this,
            "This app needs access to your storage to read files.",
            PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE,
            android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
            android.Manifest.permission.READ_MEDIA_AUDIO
            )
    }

    override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(
        requestCode: Int,
        permissions: Array<out String>,
        grantResults: IntArray
    ) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults)
        EasyPermissions.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults, this)
    }

    override fun onPermissionsDenied(requestCode: Int, perms: List<String>) {
        if(EasyPermissions.somePermissionPermanentlyDenied(this, perms)) {
            SettingsDialog.Builder(this).build().show()
        }
    }

    override fun onPermissionsGranted(requestCode: Int, perms: List<String>) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Permission granted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }

}
```

It opens up the request prompt, but even if I accept the permission it executes this code,

```
override fun onPermissionsDenied(requestCode: Int, perms: List<String>) {
        if(EasyPermissions.somePermissionPermanentlyDenied(this, perms)) {
            SettingsDialog.Builder(this).build().show()
        }
    }
```

I want that it works properly for every API level. just not showing the prompt even if I accept the permissions.

Comment: `READ_MEDIA_AUDIO:: Works in API LEVEL 31 and above` No. Only for 33+.

Answer (score 0):

You can handle the permission check on the basis of SDK Version.
Like this:

```
private fun hasStoragePermission(): Boolean {
        return EasyPermissions.hasPermissions(
            this,
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.S)
                android.Manifest.permission.READ_MEDIA_AUDIO
            else
                android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
        )
    }
```